# Postgresql9.5alpha1 installation error

Tags: postgresql

I tried to install postgresql 9.5(alpha) Ubuntu, but after make world I got this error:

> In file included from ../../../../src/include/postgres.h:47:0,
>                            from varlena.c:15:
>           levenshtein.c: In function ‘varstr_levenshtein’:
>           ../../../../src/include/c.h:726:7: error: static assertion failed: "Levenshtein hinting mechanism restricts NAMEDATALEN"
>             do { _Static_assert(condition, errmessage); } while(0)
>
> ```
>     levenshtein.c:104:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘StaticAssertStmt’
>       StaticAssertStmt(NAMEDATALEN <= MAX_LEVENSHTEIN_STRLEN,
>
>     levenshtein.c: In function ‘varstr_levenshtein_less_equal’:
>     ../../../../src/include/c.h:726:7: error: static assertion failed: "Levenshtein hinting mechanism restricts NAMEDATALEN"
>       do { _Static_assert(condition, errmessage); } while(0)
>
>     levenshtein.c:104:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘StaticAssertStmt’
>       StaticAssertStmt(NAMEDATALEN <= MAX_LEVENSHTEIN_STRLEN,
>
>     make[4]: *** [varlena.o] Error 1
>     make[3]: *** [adt-recursive] Error 2
>     make[2]: *** [utils-recursive] Error 2
>     make[1]: *** [all-backend-recurse] Error 2
>     make: *** [world-src-recurse] Error 2
> ```

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: I was lazy and installed from the rpm at http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php Got everything up & running within minutes.

Comment: @bcrd You need to show the rest of the errors, on the lines preceding that one. Try `make -s` to remove unnecessary output. Please edit the question with more complete logs and comment here when done.

Comment: Maybe upgrade the levenshtein library? It may be postgres needs a newer one?

Comment: I upgrade the levenshtein library, but it didn't help mi....

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu you can install latest on this moment postgresql 9.5alpha2 from my ppa by this series of command from terminal:

```
sudo apt-add repository ppa:kazan417/postgresql    
sudo apt-get update     
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5 postgresql-contrib-9.5 postgresql-client-9.5
```

This commands not just install postgresql also it setup evrything you need for running postgresql.
Also you can install additional packages. or if you want harder way compile it from source by "dpkg-buildpackage" - this is better ubuntu way of compiling. And then installing by dpkg -i .
Here [link](https://launchpad.net/~kazan417/+archive/ubuntu/postgresql/+sourcepub/5287651/+listing-archive-extra) you can find more info like dsc file and orig.tar.gz for compiling.